# Eclipse Neon Quick Fix shortcut not working

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

My shortcut "CTRL + 1" (default) won't open the quick fix menu.
However when I right click -> quick fix it will open.

I tried restoring all default keys/restarting eclipse. But it all doesn't work.

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: reinstall Eclipse.

It worked.

Comment: Only possible in 3 hours

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes some shortcuts stop working without the reason but not in all project at once. For me the quick fix in such situations is: close and reopen the project that you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a bug in theming. It happens when I change the Theme to dark.
A solution is to make a new workspace.